# Entity Framwork 6 + SQLite значения по умолчанию

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбец с датой, куда должна вставляться текущая дата (для SQLite это `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`). Так вот когда я вставляю строки через сторонний DBExplorer, дата подставляется автоматом, но когда я делаю это через EF, вылетает исключение

> constraint failed NOT NULL constraint failed: Films.AddingDate

Соответственно в базе столбец `AddingDate NOT NULL`, а в модели

```
public DateTime? AddingDate { get; set; }
```

Nulled здесь нужно, потому что иначе `AddingDate` становится равным `default(DateTime)` что соответствует `0001-01-01 00:00:00`

Короче надо сделать так, чтобы в таблицу вставлялось дефолтное значение, а пользователь этим вообще не управлял (`internal set`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методом тыка нашел решение. Для того, чтобы EF не пытался внести в поле, которому присваивается автоматически сгенерированное базой значение, значение из модели, сделал следующее. В контексте переопределил

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Film>().Property(f => f.AddingDate).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
}
```

То есть сообщил EF, что поле `Film.AddingDate` устанавливается базой. В итоге мне не потребовалось в модели менять тип `DateTime` на `DateTime?` (ведь в базе данных оно NOT NULL). А для того, чтобы другим не было соблазна поменять значение даты, я сделал так

```
public DateTime AddingDate { get; protected set; }
```

То есть установил на изменение модификатор `protected`. Ну а вообще, даже если свойство изменить, в базу оно все равно не запишется.